# Searching for VB6 IDE debug bar option

Tags: ide, vb6

Do you know which is the option to display the left grey bar on code page on VB6 Ide?
It's the bar used to toggle breakpoints for debugging (same effect of f9 but using mouse click)?

It disappeared on my IDE and i can't find the option to take it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Tools | Options...`, on the `Editor Format` tab, re-check `Margin Indicator Bar`.